# Create new column conditional on day and hour of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the first two columns of this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'score': [2, 13, 24, 15, 11, 44], 
    'datetime': ["2017-08-30 07:00:00", "2017-08-30 08:00:00", "2017-08-31 07:00:00", "2017-08-31 08:00:00", "2017-08-29 21:00:00", "2017-08-28 21:00:00"],
    # 'difference': [2, 13, 22, 2, -33, 44]
})
```

I want to create a new column named `difference` *(demonstrated above as a comment)*, such that it is equal to:

- score value in that row
- score value of the day before in the same hour.

**Example:** `difference` in row 4 is equal to: score in that row - score on the day before (30th) at `08:00:00`, final value: `15 - 13 = 2`.

If the day before and same time do not exist, then the value of the score of that row is taken:

- E.g. in row 0, for time `2017-08-30 07:00:00` there is no `2017-08-29 07:00:00`, hence only the 2 is taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
before = df['datetime'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

df['difference'] = df['score'].sub(
    before.map(df.set_index('datetime')['score']), fill_value=0)
```

#### Explanation

Parse the dates in the `datetime` column using `pd.to_datetime` then subtract a `DateOffset` of `1 days` to calculate the timestamp of previous day at the same hour.

```
>>> before

0   2017-08-29 07:00:00
1   2017-08-29 08:00:00
2   2017-08-30 07:00:00
3   2017-08-30 08:00:00
4   2017-08-28 21:00:00
5   2017-08-27 21:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now `map` the `score` values to the calculated `before` column.

```
>>> before.map(df.set_index('datetime')['score'])

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     2.0
3    13.0
4    44.0
5     NaN
Name: datetime, dtype: float64
```

Then subtract mapped score values from the `score` column to get the difference.

```
>>> df

   score            datetime  difference
0      2 2017-08-30 07:00:00         2.0
1     13 2017-08-30 08:00:00        13.0
2     24 2017-08-31 07:00:00        22.0
3     15 2017-08-31 08:00:00         2.0
4     11 2017-08-29 21:00:00       -33.0
5     44 2017-08-28 21:00:00        44.0
```